# Custom failureHandler throws 401 in Spring security login

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm working on a custom login `failureHandler` in my app, and I noticed that if I type `anyRequest().authenticated()` in `authorizeRequest()` everything works, but I have no CSS on my login page, but if I type `anyRequest().permitAll()`, I have CSS on my site, and logging with wrong credentials throws 401 - unauthorized error. It only happens in my custom `failureHandler`. Can you tell me why it happens?

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**")
                .hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/user/**")
                .hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/guest*")
                .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
                .permitAll()
//          .anyRequest()
//              .authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/guest/login")
            .permitAll()
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/user/all-tasks", true)
            .failureUrl("/guest/login")
            .failureHandler(new MyAuthenticationFailureHandler())
            .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/user/logout")
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .and()
        .cors()
            .and()
        .csrf()
            .disable();
}
```

```
@Component
public class MyAuthenticationFailureHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
        super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);
        request.getSession().setAttribute("error", true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> logging with wrong credentials throws 401 - unauthorized error

Because you are doing :

```java
.failureUrl("/guest/login")
.failureHandler(new MyAuthenticationFailureHandler())
```

and what are done by `failureUrl()` will be reset by the subsequent `failureHandler()`.So the customised `SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler` do not configure with `failureUrl` yet and hence it will send 401 if the authentication fails since it does know which URL to redirect to.Change it to :

```java
.failureHandler(new MyAuthenticationFailureHandler("/guest/login"))
```

should redirect to "/guest/login" if authentication fails.

> I noticed that if I type `anyRequest().authenticated()` in
>   `authorizeRequest()` everything works, but I have no CSS on my login
>   page, but if I type `anyRequest().permitAll()`, I have CSS on my site,

Because in case of `anyRequest().authenticated()` , the CSS 's URL also required an authenticated user to access. But in login page , the user must not be authenticated. Because if they are authenticated , it does not make sense that they can go to login page.So no CSS will be shown in login page since only unauthenticated users can go to it.

You have to exclude all the related url resources required by login page to work from any protections by configuring `WebSecurity`. Everyone should access them :

```java
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring()
       .antMatchers("/css/**")
       .antMatchers("/anyThingRequiredByLoginPageToWork/**");
}
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you! But I have a question, what is a potential risk of keeping in my code `anyRequest.permitAll()`?

Comment: then all the URL besides '/admin/**"' , '/user/**' can be accessed by everyone without login.